# Oracle outer join and constant values

Tags: sql, oracle, join

**====== Original question ======**

I've multiple outer joins on constants as below in the SQL:

```
select .. from CLAS MDP, CLAS ORG_CNTRY, CLAS BEN_CNTRY
AND   ORG_CNTRY.LAS_ID(+) = 'COUNTRY_LOOKUP'
AND   ORG_CNTRY.CB_DT     = MDP.CB_DT
AND   BEN_CNTRY.LAS_ID(+) = 'COUNTRY_LOOKUP'
AND   BEN_CNTRY.CB_DT     = MDP.CB_DT
```

Is the above query equivalent to the below? Please advise.

```
select ... from
CLAS MDP left join CLAS ORG_CNTRY on ORG_CNTRY.LAS_ID = 'COUNTRY_LOOKUP' left 
join CLAS BEN_CNTRY on BEN_CNTRY.LAS_ID = 'COUNTRY_LOOKUP' where ORG_CNTRY.CB_DT     
= MDP.CB_DT and BEN_CNTRY.CB_DT     = MDP.CB_DT
```

**======Follow-up question =======**

@Used_By_Already, @Gordon Linoff thanks for the response.

However, my actual query is little more than what I originally posted. it goes like:

```
MDP.CLAS_ID   = 'DIS_PARAMETERS'
AND   MDP.CB_DT    = <<BusinessDate>>
AND   ACCT.ACCT_NO  = TXN.ACCT_NO
AND   MDP.CTRY_CD   = TXN.REC_CTRY_CD
AND   TXN.CB_DT    BETWEEN ACCT.START_DT and ACCT.END_DT
AND   ORG_CNTRY.CLAS_ID(+) = 'COUNTRY_LOOKUP'
AND   ORG_CNTRY.CB_DT     = MDP.CB_DT
AND   BEN_CNTRY.CLAS_ID(+) = 'COUNTRY_LOOKUP'
AND   BEN_CNTRY.CB_DT     = MDP.CB_DT
AND   TXN.SEND_CTRY_CD  = ORG_CNTRY.CLAS_SCHM_CD(+)
AND   TXN.RCIP_CTRY_CD  = BEN_CNTRY.CLAS_SCHM_CD(+)
```

Can this be re-written as below? Please advise.

```
select ...
from 
CLAS MDP left join CLAS ORG_CNTRY on ORG_CNTRY.CB_DT = MDP.CB_DT 
    AND ORG_CNTRY.LAS_ID = 'COUNTRY_LOOKUP' 
right join ACCT_TRAN TXN on ORG_CNTRY.CLAS_SCHM_CD = TXN.SEND_CTRY_CD
left join CLAS BEN_CNTRY on BEN_CNTRY.CB_DT = MDP.CB_DT 
    AND BEN_CNTRY.LAS_ID = 'COUNTRY_LOOKUP' 
right join ACCT_TRAN TXN on BEN_CNTRY.CLAS_SCHM_CD = TXN.RCIP_CTRY_CD
```

Comment: No. Joins and filter predicates can both go in a `join` clause, even though with inner joins it's more logical to separate filter predicates out and put them in the `where` clause. The fact that this means inner and outer joins are not interchangeable is the one thing I don't like about the syntax.

Comment: a very informal, largely unwritten, rule exists, which is: *"don't use right outer joins"* There is certainly no reason to do so here. However you are asking for a definitive answer without any access to the data. It can only be a best  guess and it would need to be tested. Note you **CANNOT declare the table alias TXN twice**, that will never work.

Answer (score 2):

Each of these predicates mentions 2 tables which makes them "**join conditions**" (not "filtering conditions").

```
    AND   ORG_CNTRY.CB_DT = MDP.CB_DT
    AND   BEN_CNTRY.CB_DT = MDP.CB_DT
```

If converting from the "old fashioned" Oracle join syntax then those "**join conditions**" **MUST** be moved to the join syntax, like this:

```
select ...
from CLAS MDP 
left join CLAS ORG_CNTRY on ORG_CNTRY.CB_DT = MDP.CB_DT
left join CLAS BEN_CNTRY on BEN_CNTRY.CB_DT = MDP.CB_DT
```

Hopefully it now becomes clear that the other predicates (on the constants) would not make sense in the where clause or the outer joins would be overridden to be equivalent to inner joins. So these also need to be moved to the joins and you end up with:

```
select ...
from CLAS MDP 
left join CLAS ORG_CNTRY on ORG_CNTRY.CB_DT = MDP.CB_DT AND ORG_CNTRY.LAS_ID = 'COUNTRY_LOOKUP' 
left join CLAS BEN_CNTRY on BEN_CNTRY.CB_DT = MDP.CB_DT AND BEN_CNTRY.LAS_ID = 'COUNTRY_LOOKUP'
```

---

Whilst the following note is by no means mandatory, I recommend listing the "prior table" first in the newer join syntax (note **MDP** is listed *prior* to either of the other tables):

```
select ...
from CLAS MDP
left join CLAS ORG_CNTRY on MDP.CB_DT = ORG_CNTRY.CB_DT AND ORG_CNTRY.LAS_ID = 'COUNTRY_LOOKUP' 
left join CLAS BEN_CNTRY on MDP.CB_DT = BEN_CNTRY.CB_DT AND BEN_CNTRY.LAS_ID = 'COUNTRY_LOOKUP'
```

One thing that can be overlooked when converting from the older (very messy) where clause syntax is that order listing tables in the FROM list did not matter. However when using syntax such as *join t2 ON t1.x = t2.y* the table t1 MUST be listed before t2 is or the join will produce an error. I find that listing the "prior table" first helps ensure this is true.

---

By the way: In the "archaic syntax" you would need the following to properly form those two outer joins:

```
select .. from CLAS MDP, CLAS ORG_CNTRY, CLAS BEN_CNTRY
AND   ORG_CNTRY.LAS_ID(+) = 'COUNTRY_LOOKUP'
AND   ORG_CNTRY.CB_DT(+)     = MDP.CB_DT
AND   BEN_CNTRY.LAS_ID(+) = 'COUNTRY_LOOKUP'
AND   BEN_CNTRY.CB_DT(+)     = MDP.CB_DT
```

Otherwise you have formed inner joins by requiring a column value in one table to be equal to a field in some value in another table (& hence unmatched values are disallowed).

---

**Additional query** (more joins)

Once you have established a LEFT JOIN, and you want to relate another table to that left joined table continue to use LEFT JOIN. Also note that every table alias MUST BE UNIQUE, so if you need to join any table more than once make sure the alias used isn't the same.

```
SELECT
      *
FROM CLAS MDP
LEFT JOIN CLAS ORG_CNTRY ON MDP.CB_DT = ORG_CNTRY.CB_DT AND ORG_CNTRY.LAS_ID = 'COUNTRY_LOOKUP'
LEFT JOIN CLAS BEN_CNTRY ON MDP.CB_DT = BEN_CNTRY.CB_DT AND BEN_CNTRY.LAS_ID = 'COUNTRY_LOOKUP'
LEFT JOIN ACCT_TRAN TXN1 ON ORG_CNTRY.CLAS_SCHM_CD = TXN1.SEND_CTRY_CD
LEFT JOIN ACCT_TRAN TXN2 ON BEN_CNTRY.CLAS_SCHM_CD = TXN2.RCIP_CTRY_CD
```

Comment: can you please help to verify my approach with the follow-up question

Answer (score 1):

Probably not.  The sensible query with `LEFT JOIN`s would be:

```
select ...
from CLAS MDP left join
     CLAS ORG_CNTRY
     on ORG_CNTRY.CB_DT = MDP.CB_DT AND ORG_CNTRY.LAS_ID = 'COUNTRY_LOOKUP' left join
     CLAS BEN_CNTRY
     on BEN_CNTRY.CB_DT = MDP.CB_DT AND BEN_CNTRY.LAS_ID = 'COUNTRY_LOOKUP'
```

Forget about the archaic `(+)` syntax.  As presented, I'm not even sure that it results in an outer join.

Comment: can you please help to verify my approach with the follow-up question